# Laravel Query Builder - Need to modify query result

Tags: php, laravel

I created a very simple query but the laravel builder added additional query which I will like to remove.

```
\DB::enableQueryLog();
  App\Proj::whereNotNull('deleted_at')->paginate(20);
dd(\DB::getQueryLog());
```

The query that came out of it is as follows:

```
select * from `projs` where `deleted_at` is not null and `projs`.`deleted_at` is null
```

To get a good result, the query needed is:

```
select * from `projs` where `deleted_at` is not null
```

Without the 'and ...' in the query result statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the soft deleted Proj entries use `onlyTrashed()`

```
\DB::enableQueryLog();
  App\Proj::onlyTrashed()->paginate(20);
dd(\DB::getQueryLog());
```

if you want to include the soft deleted ones in a query, use `withTrashed()`

```
App\Proj::withTrashed()->paginate(20);
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `Proj` model probably uses `SoftDeletes` Trait, thus the `deleted_at is not null` part is added by default.

Get the deleted ones like:

```
App\Proj::onlyTrashed()->paginate(20)
```

See here https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#retrieving-only-soft-deleted-models

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but how can I have a list of only records that have been flagged as deleted?

Comment: Just modified my answer, thought you wanted the non-deleted.

Answer (score 2):

don't use whereNotNull('deleted_at') because if you are using soft delete then laravel automatically run this

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but how can I have a list of the deleted only?

Comment: This is one perfect answer as a query builder. Cause often 'null' can not be considered as all databases may not recognize it. so whereNotNull() is the right choice to check if the field is not 'null'